# Xamarin iOS notification with NotificationHub displayed without calling DidReceiveRemoteNotification when app is in background

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm creating an App with xamarin using notification hub for the notification

When the app is in foreground i'm able to process the notification with my implementation of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in the WillPresentNotification method and displaying correct title and other data

While when the app is in backgorund or inactive the notification is displayed without passing through any method, so i can't format it

I already tried to add "content-available" as a parameter and what happend was that the plain notification, not formatted correctly is first displayed, then DidReceiveRemoteNotification is fired and another notification, with the correct format is displayed

Answer (score 0):

iOS handles notifications differently depending on if your app is in the foreground or background.

App in foreground:
runs through `DidReceiveRemoteNotification`.

App in background:
does not immediately run through `DidReceiveRemoteNotification`. The OS generates and displays the notification. Upon selecting the notification, the app will run through `DidReceiveRemoteNotification`.

see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions)

Comment: thanks, i understand now, do you know if there is a way to intercept or stop the automatic display? right now i'm trying using silent notification as per the documentation you linked, but maybe there is a better way

Comment: Sounds like you want [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit). This is a notification intended only for your app to handle and doesn't display to the user.